# How do I match a string up to a number in python using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regular expressions, but I'd like to match a string up to when the numbers start.

So just say I have:

`EEEE1234`

Then I would like to extract only:

`EEEE`

I tried searching, but I find regular expressions confusing and the best way I think is through examples. Any thoughts? Also, any insight into any regex code generators or good tutorials on this?

Comment: For a tutorial, you can't go far wrong with http://regular-expressions.info/

Comment: It's likely a better idea to learn and write regular expressions by hand rather than using a generator, because they're a little cryptic as it is, a generator would likely make things even harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use \D to mean "not a digit":

```
r"^\D+"
```

Example:

```
import re

s = "EEEE1234"
print re.match(r"^\D+",s).group(0)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/3fg1k)

You've already got some recommendations for tutorials, but I'd like to also add that if you haven't yet seen the [documentation for the `re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), you should bookmark that and read that after you've read a more basic tutorial. The documentation is not beginner level but it has some very useful tips that are specific to using regular expressions in Python, and there also some examples near the end.

Comment: This would also match if there are no numbers in the string.

Comment: @Radu: True, but he didn't say what should happen if there are no numbers in the string so it's not necessary a problem. I'll ask him about that case.

Comment: Yes that's fine if it matches if there's no numbers. That's desired behavior. Thanks a lot Mark! I will definitely check out the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

- `\d`             = one digit (numbers 0 through 9)
- `\D`             = one non-digit
- `\D+`           = one or more non-digits
- `\D+\d`       = one or more non-digits followed by one digit
- `(\D+)\d`   = one or more non-digits captured in a group followed by one digit

So, if you have a string

```
str = 'EEEE1234'
```

then you can [`import re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) and use [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) to match the regular expression on the string:

```
re.match(r'(\D+)\d', str)
```

This will get you a match object, from which you can extract the contents of the group:

```
re.match(r'(\D+)\d', str).group(1)
```

This will contain `EEEE`.

Comment: Thank you!!! This was extremely helpful as the next thing I was trying to figure out was matching EEE123EE up to EEE123. Of course, this was r"^(\D+)(\d+). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one thing that might help is to view regular expressions as a tool that, first of all, performs **matching** operations. The searching, substitution, and string splitting are all consequences of this ability. One example, depending on how you'd like to extract the desired parts:

```
r"^(\D+)\d*"
```

This regex uses a *capturing group* that you can later reference.

For learning purposes, there are many resources, as has been mentioned. If you're interested in how regexes work, or want to understand them a little better, you may want to read a bit about [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Answer (score 0):

If we're specifically looking for when the letters meet numbers, I'd do something like:

```
re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+(?=\d+)')
```

Which will match it only when it's followed by numbers, but not return the numbers themselves.  That way you also get to avoid groups, which can be messy.